# How to store pandas columne names for programmatic access?

Tags: python, pandas

I am wondering what is best practice for storing pandas column names. I load data into a dataframe and then access columns by their name.

However, I do not want to hardcode strings into my program as there is no linting support and if I change the column name I need to manually hunt for the string.

Currently, the best thing I've come up with is using an Enum.

```py
class Col(enum.Enum):
    col1 = 1
    col2 = 2
    col3 = 3
```

and then accessing the columns as `df[Col.col1.name]`

Pros: 
- nicely defined object `Col` rather than e.g. individual constants

Cons:
- long and uninformative parts  (`Col.` and `.name`)

Is there a standard way of solving this? Is there a better way?

Classes have the dot notation that is also supported by pandas. However, the downside is that there is no linting support for this. Is it possible to making autocomplete (in PyCharm)
work for `df.col1`?

Comment: If you don't need the actual names of columns, why not just access them with `iloc`: `df.iloc[:, 0]`?